# NSMediaplayer status bar bug?

Tags: xcode, video, ios5, media-player, media

I'm using `NSMediaPlayer` to play my video. I'm hiding the status bar on the top with info `plist` file. After I play the movie the status bar comes up (I guess this is a bug with media player. I've tried hiding the status bar after the media finished with this code:

```
-(void)movieFinished


{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:[player moviePlayer]];
[player release];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; //this one
}
```

Now the problem is that in my view there is a scrollview and it has loads of `UIImages` and scrollviews inside. There is a space right where the status bar should be and the scrollviews and subviews are moved down a little bit.

Is there a solution to this? A fix to `NSMediaPlayer` maybe? I've searched the net but maybe I'm not entering the right words or nobody's got an issue with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I've found the answer. If you use:

```
[player.moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
```

The status bar appears no matter what you do.

So after the movie finished you call a method with nsnotifications, in the movieFinished method you use this code to fix this issue:

```
[[self view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -20, 1024, 768)]; // this code removes the empty space from the status bar

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]; //this code removes the status bar
```

hope this helps someone